# Call contract form another contract in chaincode in HYPERLEDGER Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, smartcontracts

I'm trying to call contract form another contract inside one channel and deployed on one Chaincode('cc'). Version of HLF 1.4

```
class Contract1  extends Contract {
  constructor() {
    super('Contract1');
  }

  async testContract2(ctx) {
    const res = await ctx.stub.invokeChaincode('cc', ['test']);
    return JSON.stringify(res);
  }
}

class Contract2  extends Contract {
  constructor() {
    super('Contract2');
  }

  async test(ctx) {
    // some logic
  }
}
```

And getting error:

```
[Query]: evaluate: Query ID "[object Object]" of peer "peer0.org1.example.com:7051" failed:
 message=transaction returned with failure: Error: INVOKE_CHAINCODE failed: 
transaction ID: 82c10988ad2c7cef468cae937d2e0d0bfe649f7f9c5406498733d7ef20d387f7: 
execute failed: error sending: txid: 82c10988ad2c7cef468cae937d2e0d0bfe649f7f9c5406498733d7ef20d387f7(some-channel) exists,
 stack=Error: transaction returned with failure: Error: INVOKE_CHAINCODE failed: transaction ID:
 82c10988ad2c7cef468cae937d2e0d0bfe649f7f9c5406498733d7ef20d387f7: 
execute failed: error sending: txid: 82c10988ad2c7cef468cae937d2e0d0bfe649f7f9c5406498733d7ef20d387f7(some-channel) exists


(/hyperledger-fabric/javascript/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:845:24),status=500,
url=grpcs://localhost:7051, name=peer0.org1.example.com:7051,
grpc.max_receive_message_length=-1, grpc.max_send_message_length=-1, 
grpc.keepalive_time_ms=120000, grpc.http2.min_time_between_pings_ms=120000, 
grpc.keepalive_timeout_ms=20000, grpc.http2.max_pings_without_data=0, 
grpc.keepalive_permit_without_calls=1, name=peer0.org1.example.com:7051, 
grpc.ssl_target_name_override=peer0.org1.example.com, 
grpc.default_authority=peer0.org1.example.com, isProposalResponse=true

Failed to evaluate transaction: Error: transaction returned with failure: Error: 
INVOKE_CHAINCODE failed: transaction ID: 
82c10988ad2c7cef468cae937d2e0d0bfe649f7f9c5406498733d7ef20d387f7: execute failed: error sending: 
txid: 82c10988ad2c7cef468cae937d2e0d0bfe649f7f9c5406498733d7ef20d387f7(some-channel) exists
```

Everythoing else working as expected(calling methods from client, saving sate, etc). What I'm doing wrong? Is it impossible to call method from one contract in another in same chaincode???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR

```
class Contract1  extends Contract {
  constructor() {
    super('Contract1');
  }

  async testContract2(ctx) {
    let contract2 = new Contract2();
    const res = await contract2.test(ctx)
    .....
  }
}

class Contract2  extends Contract {
  constructor() {
    super('Contract2');
  }

  async test(ctx) {
    // some logic
  }
}
```

`ctx.stub.invokeChaincode` is designed to actually call another chaincode.  Part of the confusion is that `Contract` and `chaincode` are not exactly the same thing.

In your case, you've implemented two `Contracts` within a single chaincode.  A `Contract` is a higher level abstraction and one or more `Contracts` can be packaged within the same `chaincode`.

So you actually want a `Contract` to call a `Contract` within the same chaincode, not across two different chaincodes.

Comment: Thank you. I thought that this way will not work because contract needs some kind of specific initialization)